Reads from ec_sys file in linux causes keyboard keys to repeat
I spent the last few days experimenting with isw, and discovered that I can enable and disabled a Cooler Boost using # isw -b on/off. Eventually I used strace(was lazy to read the source code of isw), and saw that it simply wrote to /sys/kernel/debug/ec/ec0/io at offset 0x98, either a 0 to disable the cooler boost or 0x80 to enable it.
So I wanted to make a keyboard shortcut for it, and made a small C program with setuid to toggle it, its source code is as follows:
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int err = setuid(0);
    if(err) {
        perror("setuid");
        return 2;
    }

    FILE *ec = fopen("/sys/kernel/debug/ec/ec0/io", "rb+");
    if(!ec) {
        perror("fopen");
        return 1;
    }

    fseek(ec, 0x98, SEEK_SET);
    int state = fgetc(ec);
    fseek(ec, 0x98, SEEK_SET);
    if (state == 0)
        state = 0x80;
    else
        state = 0;

    fputc(state, ec);
    fclose(ec);
    return 0;
}

It did work, however, I noticed that when I executed it from the terminal, a whole bunch(about 20 or so) newlines were printed. Having no clue what could have caused them, I still went ahead and setup the keyboard shortcut Super+F1, but when I tried it, the keyboard stopped working completely, I could still navigate my system with the mouse without any lag, but the keyboard was completely unresponsive until a reboot, and the fan did not speed up.
I decided to make the keyboard shortcut execute the command in a graphical terminal instead of directly, and here it became obvious what the problem was, as soon as I Super+F1, not one, but waaaaay too many terminal windows opened up each of them trying to execute the toggle cooler executable.
My temporary solution for now is adding a sleep(1) at the beginning of the program, which works, I don't get the newlines anymore, and the shirtcut executes the command once.
The problem is that apparently when writing to the EC sys file, it is as though the keyboard state is fixed and cannot change for some time, causing the shortcut to repeat, ot in the terminal, causing the newline to stay down for some time.
I am curious if anybody had this problem before? and other than sleep(), is there any better solution? Is this a bug somewhere? Is it a hardware issue?
I went through the source code of linux a bit at https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/acpi/ec_sys.c#L110, but did'nt notice anything special. Eventually it's just a normal outb, which leaves the last option, it's a hardware issue the most probable, but I'm not that sure.
For information I am on Gnome Wayland, Arch linux, MSI laptop.

Since it doesn't happen when you use the isw command, maybe now is the time to read the source code to see what it's doing differently.

@Barmar Well I looked at strace, and there was nothing special. I looked at the source code later and well, there isn't anything special isw does, which makes this more weird. However I noticed that isw -c which dumps ec/io file also has the problem, so I'm guessing it is reads to ec/io that freeze the keyboard, not writes.

It might be when it reads other field related to the keyboard. Try using Unix I/O instead of stdio, to avoid buffering that reads extra data.

@Barmar Hahaha, That was exactly the problem, it didn't cross my mind at all. Thank you!!
